# OpenAm with JSF application login page redirection

Tags: jsf, openam

I am currently using OpenAm to authenticate, But I also want a normal login page where there is a normal login way as well. Now I am able to redirect to my application after successful authentication but I end up at the login page again. how do I bypass the login page to do into my application, My application runs on JSF.

For now I have a REST service which gets the token from openaman.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal login page" and "normal login way"? How are you using OpenAM at the moment? Please be more precise about your current setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the rest api of openam to create login page.